# Problem executing "checkout" in Affirm payment gateway

Tags: javascript, laravel

I was integrating affirm in my web-page using Javascript when I came across this error ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXZ2L.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/damvb.jpg)).
My application is made on Laravel framework.
I found a [thread](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus_affirm/issues/42) on github where I found that using apostrophe anywhere in the checkout body parameters results in said error. So I eliminated any apostrophe (there was one). in the body . Unfortunately, the error still persists.

Affirm api docs link: https://docs.affirm.com/affirm-developers/docs/checkout-web

Comment: Show Related code

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam
Javascript Code:
https://justpaste.it/3d4x2